# Primeng dropdown list show always Angular 6

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I want to keep dropdown always open .In bootstrap I could add open class via directive and achieve it.
I saw some options about adding random class and getting that element by `ElementRef` query selector and using toggle method on element. But nothing worked so far.
So far I want to achieve not close primeng dropdown on click outside , always stay open.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the help center to see what questions you can ask. Please show your attempts you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: why you don't use listbox component